# JavaFX ComboBox drop down action

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am trying to make the arrow button disappear entirely from my ComboBox and at the same time i want to make my ComboBox open the dropdown menu when i click on it.

Firstly, with what i have made the arrow is transparent but still works. So what i want is to delete it entirely. How am i suppose to do that?

ComboBox Java Code

```
searchBar = new ComboBox<>();
searchBar.setEditable(true);
searchBar.setMinWidth(1100);
searchBar.setPromptText("type here");
```

CSS Code:

```
.combo-box {
    -fx-border-width: 0.2px;
    -fx-border-color: #87C6C8;
    -fx-border-radius: 45px;
    -fx-background-radius: 45px;
    -fx-font-size: 15px;
    -fx-font-weight: 100;
    -fx-font-family: 'arial';
}
.combo-box .arrow,
.combo-box .arrow-button{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.combo-box-base:editable > .text-field{
    -fx-border-width: 0.5px;
    -fx-border-color: #87C6C8;
    -fx-border-radius: 50px;
    -fx-background-radius: 50px;
    -fx-font-size: 15px;
    -fx-font-weight: 100;
    -fx-font-family: 'arial';
}
```

Result:
[image]

How can delete that?

Secondly, how can i make an action when i click the ComboBox the menu drops down?

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Provide the Java code you use to create the combo box.

Comment: I just updated the post with the code.

Comment: hmm .. why? If you need a control varying so strongly from a standard comboBox (no arrow, different opening gesture ...), implement your own, with a custom skin and behavior. BTW: one problem per question, please.